# i'm having an error starting claimcenter server as the build is not creating the webinf folder in the idea/webapp folder

Tags: server, startupscript, claimcenter

We can't start the  GW ClaimCenter server from studio because the WEB-INF folder should be generated in the BUILD of the project inside the build/idea/webapp folder but it is not and  we have the WEB-INF in deploy/ folder. If we manually copy from one location to the other we still have errors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzAMJ.png)

I tried to manually copy from one location to the other we still have errors.
I searched for the Build script to see where could be set to create the build/idea/webapp folder and the WEB-INF there, but I could not found it.
I expect  the BUILD to generate the WEB-INF in the right place.

Comment: Hi Paulo, given the age of this question I'm assuming you moved this forward on your own.  For future reference, please add the "guidewire" tag so your questions get more immediate attention.  I'm going to add the xCenter tags to my watch list, sorry I missed this one previously.